# How effective are unsolicited job applications?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, applications

There are particular companies that I would like to work for, but often the positions they have advertised are above my level (ie. require more experience).

I figure it can't hurt to send them and email expressing why I'd like to work for them, and what I can offer them, but generally how successful is this likely to be?

Comment: ... but I would not let that deter you if you can spare the time ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It certainly can't hurt to send a resume - I always recommend giving it a shot, since you never know.

The unsolicited resume submission process can be pretty brutal.  Any company that is advertising on a high-traffic medium (Monster, LinkedIn, etc.) is likely to get so many submissions that they are forced into a fairly brutal accept/reject process.  So you may not get much of a response, but then it can't hurt.  Generally the bigger the company is, the more well known it is, and the wider it is broadcasting an open position, the more likely it is that they will be deluged.

My thought would be to give it a shot, but don't invest days and days in writing a lovingly hand-crafted cover letter.  Do customize it, and keep it on topic, but don't invest vast amounts of time in a process that is likely to chew through your submission pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that many companies only accept resumes against a specific job opening they are advertising. Unless there is a exact match between a newly opened position and a recently advertised position they won't look at resumes submitted to previous openings. They feel that many will be stale, because the good candidates may have found jobs.

Unsolicited resumes/applications will generally not go very far. If they don't match the job being advertised they will be rejected and lost in the system.

The best way is to have somebody on the inside. They may see more job openings on the internal listing. Many of these companies will provide a referral bonus to the employee who submits the resume of somebody who fills a key position. The inside person may also know about job openings before they are even advertised.

You may need to network by using a site like LinkedIn to find people you know that work in the company. Then ask them to submit your resume.